# Dalvik internal exception when trying to access Google Play Game Services via NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play-games, dalvik

When I try to initialize the google play game services via the Builder, as in examples, I get the following exception (resulting in a crash).

```
    Exception in dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.loadClass: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    Didn't find class \"com.google.android.gms.games.NativeSdkCallbacks\" 
    on path: 
    DexPathList[[zip file
    \"/data/user/0/com.xxx.yyy.LocalDebug/app_.gpg.classloader/2e190de0913242cfb3e30a895073c67e_games.jar\"], 
    nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]].
```

I have no idea how to debug this

*Notes:*
I have set both `gpg::AndroidInitialization::android_main(...)` and `platform_configuration_.SetActivity(state->activity->clazz)` before executing the Builder.

I'm using the following dependencies, although I have tried toggling them back and forth in order to get different results:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1'
```